# assign List to derived type of List

Tags: c#, collections, casting

I need to convert a generic List to a custom collection. Have a look:

```
public class MyCustomType
{ }


public class MyCustomTypeCollection : List<MyCustomType>, IMyCustomTypeCollection
{

}

public interface IMyCustomTypeCollection : IList<MyCustomType>
{

}

public class DemoCast
{

    public void Cast()
    {
        IMyCustomTypeCollection collection = new List<MyCustomType>();
    }
}
```

How does the cast has to look like?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does `List<MyCustomType>` implements `IMyCustomTypeCollection` ? **NO** ... ergo it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
 IMyCustomTypeCollection collection = new MyCustomTypeCollection();
```

In this case `collection` will be a `MyCustomTypeCollection` which is a `List<MyCustomType>` AND a `IMyCustomTypeCollection => IList<MyCustomType>`

You don't need the `List<MyCustomType>` since you already have the `IList<MyCustomType>` through `MyCustomTypeCollection`

Comment: Well, thanks. But in my case that's simply not possible. The example is - as always - the abstraction of the real problem.

Comment: I don't know your precise need and I get that this is just an example. Steel I point out that in your case you need to have a class implementing `IMyCustomTypeCollection`, your `MyCustomTypeCollection`class does. So you can use this type and have the expected behavior (you will have a `List`)